Heat equation in an unbounded domain
so, I'm considering the following problem:
\begin{equation} \label{chap2:GDiffusionSystem}
        \begin{aligned}
            & \frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(r,t) = C \, \Delta G(r,t) \hspace{0.5cm} (r,t) \in (0,+\infty)^2 \\
            & G(0,t>0) = 1 \\
            & G(r>0,0) = 0
        \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Where $G$ represents a correlation function that depends on $r$, the distance between the points, and $t$, which is time. The total space is the real line.
For bigger dimensions, it is necessary to change the domain of the problem, so we are not imposing the boundary condition over a zero measure set:
\begin{equation} \label{chap2:GDiffusionSystemCutoff}
        \begin{aligned}
            & \frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(r,t) = C \, \Delta G(r,t) \hspace{0.5cm} (r,t) \in (h,+\infty) \times (0,+\infty) \\
            & G(h,t>0) = 1 \\
            & G(r>h,0) = 0,\\[2mm]
            & \mbox{Here}\ h > 0.
        \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
My question would be

Are these problems solvable analytically ?.
I have tried using the separation of variables method, but I encounter a problem with the fact that the spatial domain is unbounded.
If they are solvable, I don't know how, and, if they are
not, I would like to get a hint of the reason why the fact that the spatial domain is unbounded changes everything.
Also, is there a fundamental difference between the two problems I've posed ?.
Does incrementing the dimension change the situation significantly ?.

Thank you !.

I will set $C=1$ for the following.  If you want to reintroduce it, replace $t \mapsto Ct$.
You are right that separation of variables will not work for semi-infinite spatial domains.  Standard methods of solving such equations would be Fourier transform (only applicable in 1D) and Laplace transform methods.  I will summarise the application of the Laplace transform method to your second problem, and then why the first problem only works in 1D.
In $d$ dimensions the radially symmetric heat equation is
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r^{d-1}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^{d-1}\frac{\partial G}{\partial r}\right), \qquad G(r,0) = 0, \qquad G(h,t) = 1.
$$
Applying the Laplace transform with zero initial condition, with $\mathcal L\{G(r,t)\} = \hat G(r,s)$:
$$
r\frac{\partial^2\hat G}{\partial r^2} + (d-1) \frac{\partial \hat G}{\partial r} - rs\hat G = 0, \qquad \hat G(h,s) = \frac{1}{s}, \qquad \lim_{r\to\infty}\hat G(r,s) = 0.
$$
For $d=1$, this results in
$$
\hat G = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{s}(r-h)}}{s},
$$
which can be explicitly inverted to obtain the complementary error function solution:
$$
G = \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{r-h}{2\sqrt t}\right).
$$
Here the effect of $h$ is simply a translation, as one would expect (the heat equation in 1D is translationally invariant).  One can take $h\to 0$ with no issues.
For $d>1$ the solution to the ODE for $\hat G$ will not be as simple, and will generally involve special (Bessel) functions.  Three dimensions ($d=3$) is a special case, however, as in that case the solution is elementary:
$$
\hat G = \frac{h}{rs}e^{-\sqrt s(r-h)}
$$
which may be inverted to find
$$
G(r,t) = \frac{h}{r}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{r-h}{2\sqrt t}\right).
$$
In this solution one cannot simply take $h\to 0$.  For $r\gg h$, the solution vanishes as $h\to 0$ (roughly speaking, less `heat' is entering the system), but this limit is not uniformly valid (as it does not hold when $r = O(h)$).  In fact this solution can be scaled to be independent of $h$, assuming $h>0$.  Let $\rho = r/h$ and $\tau = t/h^2$, then
$$
G = \frac{1}{\rho}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{\rho-1}{2\sqrt \tau}\right)
$$
(this scale property will be true in all dimensions, and for all $d>1$, $G$ will be undefined at $\rho=0$).

Just to check, I suppose that, in my case, the equation that would result after applying the Laplace transform would be:
$r\frac{\partial^2\hat G}{\partial r^2} - rs\hat G = 0$
Is this correct?

Also, is this limit correct $\lim_{r\to\infty}\hat G(r,s) = 0$? Shouldn't it correspond to the initial condition? Why are you taking $r \to +\infty$?

The general solution is  the Gaussian $G(t,x)= t^{-1/2} e^{- x^2/t}$ for a $\delta(x)$ source at $t=0$.
It follows that convolutions of  Gaussians with start distributions are solutions. A very easy solution is $\text{erfc}(x/\sqrt(t))$. For your problem, pin the center of $\mathrm{erfc}$ to $(0,1)$ for all times:
$$G(t,x)= \text{min}\left(\text{erfc}(\ \frac{x}{\sqrt t}\ )\ + \ 1 \ , \ 1\ \right) $$
